# Why shipping error message not change

Tags: shipping, payment-methods, shipping-methods, shipment, global-messages

Message is so that I can't customize it. 
"Displayed Error Message" in Admin -> system -> Config -> Shipping Methods 
The question is : Why shipping error message not change.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshot, it seems that you have made the changes for a particular store/website. So, please change ***Displayed Error Message*** in Default Configuration and check again.